# Isotropy of ternary quadratic forms over global fields

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $k$ be a global field and $q$ a ternary quadratic form over $k$.

> Is it true that $q_v$ is isotropic for all but finitely many places $v$ of $k$?

I'm looking for a confirmation of this, and if possible a reference.

I know that this is true for $k = \mathbb Q$, because a ternary quadratic form is isotropic over $\mathbb Q_p$ iff its Hasse invariant equals the Hilbert symbol $(-1, -d)_p$, where $d$ is the discriminant of $q$.

**Edit:** I have a proof now, except when $char(k) = 2$.

Comment: [Cholesky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition) sends $q(x) = x^\top M x$ to $q(x) = \sum_j a_j (Lx)_j^2$ for some $a_j \in k$ and $L \in GL_n(k)$. Say $M\in GL_n(k)$ so $a_j \ne 0$ it reduces to finding a $k_v$-point of $ \sum_j a_j y_j^2 = 0$, from Hensel lemma it is about the points on the reduction $\bmod \pi_v$ that we can count from character sums (obtaining some kind of [Hasse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) bound)

Comment: For all but finitely many $v$ all the $a_j \in O_{k_v}^\times$, if one is quadratic residue and another is non-residue in $O_{k_v}/(\pi_v)$ then it is easy so the only case to check is when all 3 are quadratic residues or non-residues, both reduce to the case $q(x) = \sum_j x_j^2$

Comment: I see; so it reduces to the fact that every element of a finite field is a sum of two squares, the thing one proves using the combinatorial argument/pigeonhole principle. Cool. What about characteristic 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: For $k$ of characteristic not $2$, one can bring $q$ in the form $ax^2+by^2+cz^2$. When $v(2) = 0$, which is the case for almost all $v$, by Hensel's lemma any nonzero isotropic vector (automatically nonsingular) mod a prime element $\pi_v$ of the valuation ring $\mathcal O_{k_v}$ lifts to $k_v$.

For almost all $v$ one has $a, b, c \in O_{k_v}^\times$. Thus it suffices to show that a nondegenerate quadratic form $ax^2+by^2+cz^2$ over a finite field $F$ (of characteristic $\neq 2$) is isotropic, i.e. that $ax^2+by^2$ represents $-c$. Let $|F| = N$, so that $|F^2| = \frac{N+1}2$. The sets $aF^2$ and $-c-bF^2$ intersect, and we are done.

I don't know about $char(k) = 2$.